# Can't get a simple javascript prompt working

Tags: javascript, html, prompt

```
<html>
    <title>adsfasdf</title>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
          <script type="text/javascript">
        function editDates()
        {
        var dates = prompt("Fill in date(s) of absence", "Example: Travel 1/7 - 2/10");
        }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="#000088">



    <table cellspacing="0" border="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%" height="100%">
        <tr>
           <td>name</td><td>

                <form class="r1c1" method="link" action="index.html" onClick="editDates();">
                <input type="button" name="submit" value="Edit"/></form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't think you can put `onclick` in the `form` tag.

Comment: the question is: this doesn't work, why? ive also trid putting it into a <body onLoad="functionHere();"> and into the input tag itself but neither worked

Comment: what do u mean it doesn't work...the prompt isn't poping up or the form is not submitting?

Comment: Fyi, prompting for a date like that is a horrible idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this:

```
<script type=type="text/javascript">
```

should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/hDpyN/

Comment: Besides that, using `prompt()` sets a javascript variable to the returned value, and does nothing at all with the form.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
   <input type="button" name="submit" value="Edit" onClick="editDates();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>asdfasdf</title>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="#000088">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function editDates()
    {
        var dates = prompt("Fill in date(s) of absence", "Example: Travel 1/7 - 2/10");
    }
    </script>

    <table cellspacing="0" border="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%" height="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>name</td><td>

                <form class="r1c1" method="link" action="index.html" >
                <input type="button" name="submit" value="Edit" onclick="editDates();" />
                </form>
                </td>
    </tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

You need to use either onsubmit in the form or onclick in the button.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the `onClick` to `onSubmit` in the form tag:

```
<form class="r1c1" method="link" action="index.html" onSubmit="editDates();">
```

and change the `input` to type submit

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit"/>
```

Here is an example with the changes above: **[JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/7Z33z/)**